# Sharing a paw file in plain text

Tags: paw-app

In Paw, it was possible to easily share a paw file in a repository as part of the documentation because it was stored in plain text, making changes to it legible.
Artsy is doing it in its [energy project](https://github.com/artsy/energy/blob/master/docs/Folio.paw) and they wrote some [blog posts](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2016/04/14/net-working-with-paw/) about this.

However, since the 3.x release, it appears that the file is now stored in binary format.

Am I missing a hidden option to save in xml format or is the feature completely gone?

Comment: We have lots of issues with Plain text files being corrupted durring merges. The file contains lots of string and integer based references to Core Data structs. Even if the xml is clean these references get broken durring merges and results in completely unpredictable bugs in Paw. Eg an object that looks to us as a URL is actually a dynamic value etc. These bugs build up over time and result in a very much degraded experience that we just can't predict or fix. What we will be adding soon is Public tags to our cloud syncing service. We could also save out the format we send to the cloud as json

Comment: I also prefer the xml .paw files. We never had any problems with corruption (maybe we were just lucky?) and it worked a lot better with version control (ie. just being able to eyeball the diffs between revisions). I understand the binary saves solve a host of problems but it's a worse solution for us. I would have preferred the new format was an option one could opt in/out off.